# How to pass branch/commit to Could Run instance?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, continuous-integration, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-build

I have several projects that run on Google Cloud Run. Cloud Build connects each instance to a corresponding branch of a Git repository. Each time a commit is pushed to a branch, a build is triggered to update the Cloud Run instance.

I'd like to be able to show information about the build within the Cloud Run application (e.g. branch and commit that the build has been built from). How can I pass this information from the repo/commit/build to the instance?

Comment: You have the information in Cloud Build when it runs. You can get the data and paste them in your container somewhere. Then you have to serve them. Depends on your implementation, but nothing special to do here.

Answer (score 1):

As [@guillaume blaquiere](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11372593/guillaume-blaquiere) stated in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72930816/how-to-pass-branch-commit-to-could-run-instance#comment128815633_72930816):

> You have the information in Cloud Build when it runs. You can get the data and paste them in your container somewhere. Then you have to serve them. Depends on your implementation.